# SugarCRM override/overload PDF generation

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, sugarcrm

I am very new to SugarCRM, and have a need to override the behaviour of the automated PDF generation.

I'd like to reuse the generic PDF generation, because my need is common to all modules and is:
- I'd like to check the value of some fields before putting it in the pdf
- this could be achieved by calling a web service to know what value to put in the PDF.
- this is to check against some compliance rule.

Would it be possible to override, or overload this generic function?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start to work with the PDF generation in Sugar is this page: http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Architecture/SugarPDF/index.html

Comment: Thanks Cédric. From the document I understand that I can specialize some pdf generation, like for contacts, opportunities, ... What if I want to have an impact on any pdf report, on any field? (e.g. On any report that can be generated in PDF i'f like to mask (e.g. 123XXX XXX XXX 123) some field values, based on some rules?. Is it possible to do something like this(the generic code calling a custom method for each field)? Many thanks

Comment: I will create a specific question for this. Thanks